# Visual Studio 2010 installation issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7

I've tried to install Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7, but failed on every occasion, however, I've tried to give all the possible privileges, also, I've used a tool to remove everything related to it, and reinstalled after that, but to no avail.
I've repeatedly had this issue:

```
[02/22/11,09:51:20] Microsoft .NET Framework 4: [2] Error code 9 for this component means "The storage control block address is invalid.
"
[02/22/11,09:51:21] Microsoft .NET Framework 4: [2] Component Microsoft .NET Framework 4 returned an unexpected value.
[02/22/11,09:51:21] Microsoft .NET Framework 4: [2] Return from system messaging: The storage control block address is invalid.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried googling this issue?

[SP4 missing](http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Windows/2000/Q_20782945.html)
[Directory permission](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxsetupprerelease/thread/fc4c6649-8414-48b6-a104-7410955f2de5)

Comment: yes, I've tried to google the answer and the information found didn't solve the problem.

Comment: what about reinstalling .net 4?

Comment: I've reinstalled again and again .NET, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Should be a dive:\VCSExpress\wcu\dotNetFramework\ folder on the installation media. If is not an iso dvd then look in the log file generated by installer and search for the .msi or .exe file that was run. Manually run dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe and then check into the folder were was unpacked for setup and run setup.exe /x86 or setup.exe /x64
After the is validated the version prerequired by the installer the vs setup should work.